# Create Automate Null Alert for our Data

Tags: google-bigquery, null

I want to create an automate alert for our data such as null, unequal amount, etc. It'll send to our email. The data stored in bigquery. How do i create this?

it automatically send to our email if the database have null value, empty value, unequal.

e.g
Look!
Table invoice have 0 rows detected. You can check from XX, and XY table.

or for the advance
Look!
Table invoice have 0 rows detected. You can check from XX, and XY table. This causes because XYZ.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to resolve this request is to develop a custom solution on top of app engine or cloud functions, so that you can run your own queries and trigger email notifications.

This approach will not alert you in real-time but based on an schedule.

The other option if your use case is related to INSERT statements and real-time analysis is to take advantage of the logging alerts.

This will trigger an alert based on INSERT events, so you need to build your own query and setup the alert accordingly.

You can start with something like this:

```
resource.type="bigquery_resource"
protoPayload.methodName="jobservice.insert"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a custom solution, it sounds like the [Great Expectations](https://greatexpectations.io/) framework could be a good fit for you.

This is a system for defining properties you expect of your data. It can be connected to BigQuery. [It can be configured to send you emails](https://docs.greatexpectations.io/docs/guides/validation/validation_actions/how_to_trigger_email_as_a_validation_action/) if your tests ('expectations') fail.

You would still need to host the system yourself (they have a cloud solution coming in 2023).

If you want to get started fast and don't have easy access to hosting, you could also consider DBT (data build tool). DBT can connect to BigQuery and allows you to run tests (though this is not its main purpose). These tests can include checks for null data. You can write custom tests for more complex checks.

I mention it because they already have a paid for cloud solution, DBT Cloud, and yes, [you can send email notifications](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/deploy/job-notifications) if your tests fail. Depending on circumstances, this could be the fastest way to get what you want.